# If G is a group, $H< G^{|G|}$ and $|H|\geq 2^{|G|}$, then can $H$ be cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let G be a group, $H< G^{|G|}$ and $|H|\geq 2^{|G|}$. Can $H$ be a cyclic group?

By $G^{|G|}$ I mean the direct product of $|G|$ copies of $G$.

I was wondering if someone could help me about the above question.

Comment: Is $H$ a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @JoeShmo Yes, it is.

Comment: I am not quite getting the question. If $H=G^{|G|}$ and $|G|>2$ the two conditions are satisfied, yet $G^{|G|}$ is not cyclic in general.

Comment: $H$ can't be meant to be a subgroup of $G$, can it? There's no way for $|H| \ge 2^{|G|}$ then.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G^{|G|}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Okay, but then why did you explicitly write $\leq$?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Sorry, I'll edit it.

Comment: Okay, with you edit I understand the question. You're asking whether it *can be* cyclic, not asking whether it is cyclic.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip You are right. Thank you very much for your nice answer.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is finite? It's not clear from the notation in the question.

Comment: @GregMartin Generally $G$ is not finite.

Comment: If your intention was that $G$ might be infinite, why did you accept the posted answer that assumes $G$ is finite?

Comment: @GregMartin I thought that the proof could be true for infinite case, as well. Could you please guide me for the infinite case?

Comment: It looks like the OP didn't understand his own question. It makes only real sense when $G$ is finite and $H$ is a subgroup of $G^{|G|}$. By the way the OP proposed a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417924/if-s-is-a-monoid-a-subset-ss-and-a-geq-2s-then-a-is-not-cyclic) for monoids.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I understand my own question. I think you didn't understand my question because you've been asking lots of questions there without any answer, hint or anything. I thought that it may be better to change my question from monoids to groups to get my answer. That is it.

Comment: Why did you suddenly delete the other question? You finally said it came from a paper, but which paper??

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Because I didn't want to waste other people's time. It comes from Corollary 1 in the paper "On regular torsionless S-posets" by "Roghaieh Khosravi".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $n=|G|$. Let $(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$ be an element of $G^{n}$. Then it is of order $\leq n$ since $(g_1,\ldots,g_n)^n=(g_1^n,\ldots,g_n^n)=(e,\ldots, e)$. So any cyclic subgroup of $G^n$ has order $\leq n$. But $n<2^n$, so there is no $H$ as in your question.